# How to access RabbitMq publicly

Tags: centos, rabbitmq

I have installed & setup the Rabbitmq on Centos remote server. Later I created an file "rabbitmq.config" and added the line

> [{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]

and then restarted the rabbitmq server. Again tried to login the rabbitmq management web interface from my local machine using the guest credentials, but getting

> login failed

error message.What is the proper way to empty the loopback user settings for Rabbitmq in Centos.

Comment: How did you get this working?

Comment: I put this at `rabbitmq.config`, then restart failed. Note that, you have to put a dot at the end, so correct context is: `[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].`

Answer (score 44):

First of all connect to your rabbitmq server machine using ssh client so as to be able to run `rabbitmqctl` (like puTTY) & get into the sbin directory of rabbit installation

1. you need to create a user for any vhost on that system (here I use default vhost `"/"`)

`$ rabbitmqctl add_user yourName yourPass`

2. Set the permissions for that user for default vhost

`$ rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / yourName ".*" ".*" ".*"`

3. Set the administrator tag for this user (to enable him access the management pluggin)

`$ rabbitmqctl set_user_tags yourName administrator`

... and you are ready to login to your rabbitmq management gui using `yourName` and `yourPass` from any browser by pointing it to `http://"*********":15672` where `*****` is your server IP
hope it helps...

:-)

Answer (score 12):

There is an example config file, on centos do:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server-3.4.2/rabbitmq.config.example /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

Find and remove comments (and comma):

```
{loopback_users, []}
```

Then, stop rabbitmq:

```
rabbitmqctl stop
```

Now start the server:

```
service rabbitmq-server start
```

Now user "guest" can access from anywhere.

Comment: this works :) in my machine the example file was a gzip file

Answer (score 5):

Since RabbitMQ 3.3.0 there you can't use default guest/guest credentials except via localhost, (see [release notes for 3.3.0](https://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.3.0.txt) for details).

As a possible solution you can (and probably should) create custom secured user to be used for monitoring, management, etc.

Also you can use [proxy setup](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#proxy).

P.S.:

if you enabled [`loopback_users`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) check that proper config loaded (for running `NODENAME`), it is well-formed (has valid syntax and ended with `.`), management plugin activated and started and no firewall blocking rules exists.

P.P.S.:

Check that default user is `guest`, it exists and has default (`guest`) password. If you use some library to access to RabbitMQ, check that it has the same defaults as remote (`guest`:`guest`) or specify them explicitly.

Comment: He has created the rabbitmq.config file:
"If you wish to allow the guest user to connect from a remote host, you should set the loopback_users configuration item to []"

http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: Yeah, I missed that point. Thanks for notice. I've updated my suggestions to check common pitfalls.