# rabbitMQ guest login failed

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq

I have setted up rabbitMQ and its management plubin  in windows,

I found rabbitmq.config  file  with  "EXAMPLE FILE"  type  in the path of

" ...AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ "    and    " C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.3.1\etc "

I add the line   {loopback_users, []}    into this rabbitmq.config  file,  and restart the windows service,   but still can't login from another computer with  guest/guest

Am I editing the wrong config file?

Here is some relevant discussion:
[How to access RabbitMq publicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020908/how-to-access-rabbitmq-publicly)
http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: in the tutorial, the rabbitmq.config in windows is expected  in  %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\    I guess it was the issue, and copy the rabbitmq.config in that path, restart the windows service,  still not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install)

Comment: the answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install/23790606#23790606

is good, but

how can we also set the permission of "guest/guest" same as the "test/test" above?

I ran the command

rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / guest "." "." ".*"

but still can not login via guest/guest, 

the solution in the link using test/test is great, but I want to make guest/guest also work.

Comment: Use proxy setup - https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#proxy (btw, you referred to q where I mentioned proxy in answer, actually, we use proxy in production via nginx and it works perfect)

Comment: rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p for guest/guest user doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ service can't read the configuration file, this is the problem. So, your configuration file is not loaded.

The path `"..AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ"` is valid **only** if you execute `rabbitmq-server.bat` from the command prompt and not if you execute a service.

In order to work with `Windows Service` you have to configure the environment variable `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` in windows.

Open Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables and then add:

```
RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE 
path_your_configuration_file
```

as:

[image]

Then you have to uninstall and re-install rabbitmq and it works.

Please read this [discussion](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2011-January/010709.html)

I tried on windows7 with rabbitmq 3.3.1, it works corretly using guest/guest.
My configuration file is:

> [{, [{loopback_users, []}]}].

Comment: I did as you mentioned I still get this message in log file 

HTTP access denied: user 'USER' - invalid credentials

=ERROR REPORT=

Comment: Its probably easier just to set the RABBITMQ_BASE environment variable, and then all the other variables will start working (as by default they're based on RABBITMQ_BASE)

Comment: Thank you @JonEgerton ! we solved via skype with Pankaj. the error was path_your_configuration_file! He Didn't set the file name.

Comment: My point was that the config file path is implied if you set the base path - its easiest to move the whole RabbitMQ folder to somewhere not in the roaming profile, then point the base path at that.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the prior post and the comment from Jon Egerton was key to getting my Windows configuration working for the guest account remotely. Here are steps I took:

1. Set an environment variable: RABBITMQ_BASE (I set mine to
   c:\RabbitMQData)
2. Create the directory and create the rabbitmq.config file as explained in the previous post.
3. Uninstall RabbitMQ (As mentioned already, don’t skip this step. Stopping and starting RabbitMQ won’t do the trick)
4. Reinstall RabbitMQ and verify the RabbitMQ Server service started.
5. Verify that the directory specified by RABBITMQ_BASE contains the db and log sub-directories.
6. Install the RabbitMQ_Management plug-in from the command line.
7. Verify that you can now logon as the guest account using the host’s IP address or host name.