# rabbitMQ federation ACCESS_REFUSED (guest login fail)

Tags: rabbitmq

I have set up rabbitMQ federation between  two machines  A and B,  bi-direction,

but have the error

{auth_failure,"ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile."}

in the log file,  it seems the federation amqp need to access through   guest/guest  credential,  this comes to the question here:

[rabbitMQ guest login failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784080/rabbitmq-guest-login-failed)

with existing solution to set up  test/test  here :

[Can't access RabbitMQ web management interface after fresh install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850546/cant-access-rabbitmq-web-management-interface-after-fresh-install)

I tried to make  guest/guest  also work from  another machine by running :
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / guest "." "." ".*"

but still fail to login via  guest/guest on another machine,

in the rabbitMQ management web UI,   the user  test and guest look all the same:

Name
Tags
Can access virtual hosts    Has password

guest
administrator   /   ●

test
administrator   /   ●

but why  I still can't loging with guest/guest on another machine?   (test/test  works fine)

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784080/rabbitmq-guest-login-failed I just update it! hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

You are not listing what version you use, but guesstimating from your post time, I would say the issue is probably because in v 3.3.0 (released in early April 2014) they disabled guest user login remotely (see release notes [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-3.3.0.txt)), AND it looks like at some point around that time there was a change either in the way federation is supposed to be setup, or simply the yanking of the guest user made it behave differently.

Anyway, to resolve this, make sure you create your upstream with an URI in the following form:

```
amqp://your_user:your_users_password@rabbit-node-FQDN.your.domain.com/your_vhost
```

the key is in the **your_user:your_users_password** string - that was not required before 3.3 (and it still may work without it should you enable the guest user... but I don't care to try that)

hth