# Spring AMQP + RabbitMQ 3.3.5 ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I am getting below exception

> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

Configuration: RabbitMQ 3.3.5 on windows

On Config file in `%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\rabbit.config`
I have done below change as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

```
[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

I also tried creating a user/pwd - test/test doesn't seem to make it work.

Tried the Steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784080/rabbitmq-guest-login-failed) post.

Other Configuration Details are as below:

Tomcat hosted Spring Application Context:

```
<!-- Rabbit MQ configuration Start -->
    <!-- Connection Factory -->
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnFactory" virtual-host="/" username="guest" password="guest" port="5672"/>

    <!-- Spring AMQP Template -->
    <rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory" routing-key="ecl.down.queue" queue="ecl.down.queue" />

    <!-- Spring AMQP Admin -->
    <rabbit:admin id="admin" connection-factory="rabbitConnFactory"/>

    <rabbit:queue id="ecl.down.queue" name="ecl.down.queue" />

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="ecl.down.exchange">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding key="ecl.down.key" queue="ecl.down.queue"/>
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

In my Controller Class

```
@Autowired
RmqMessageSender rmqMessageSender;

//Inside a method
rmqMessageSender.submitToECLDown(orderInSession.getOrderNo());
```

In My Message sender:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("messageSender")
public class RmqMessageSender  {

    @Autowired
    AmqpTemplate                rabbitTemplate;

    public void submitToRMQ(String orderId){
        try{
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("Hello World");
        } catch (Exception e){
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }       
}
```

Above exception Block gives below Exception

---

> org.springframework.amqp.AmqpAuthenticationException: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

---

Error Log

```
  =ERROR REPORT==== 7-Nov-2014::18:04:37 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.489.0> (10.1.XX.2XX:52298 -> 10.1.XX.2XX:5672):
    {handshake_error,starting,0,
                     {amqp_error,access_refused,
                                 "PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' can only connect via localhost",
                                 'connection.start_ok'}}
```

Pls find below the pom.xml entry

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts/suggestions

Comment: Make sure that config you edit loaded.

Comment: zaq178miami, I have done few steps to make sure its loaded. Restart the service, re-boot the machine & even re-install the RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I am sure what Artem Bilan has explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26820152/2947502) might be one of the reasons for this error:

> ```
> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: 
> ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. 
> For details see the
> ```

but the solution for me was that I logged in to rabbitMQ admin page (http://localhost:15672/#/users) with the default user name and password which is guest/guest then added a new user and for that new user I enabled the permission to access it from virtual host and then used the new user name and password instead of default guest and that cleared the error.

[image]

Comment: It is not working for me either. Connection with guest:guest is fine. Connection with newUser:newPwd is giving this error. No idea why !!

Comment: I had the same problem. Following this suggestion it solved this problem.

Answer (score 73):

To complete @cpu-100 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29177677/811922),

in case you don't want to enable/use web interface, you can create a new credentials using command line like below and use it in your code to connect to RabbitMQ.

```
$ rabbitmqctl add_user YOUR_USERNAME YOUR_PASSWORD
$ rabbitmqctl set_user_tags YOUR_USERNAME administrator
$ rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / YOUR_USERNAME ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

Comment: Thank-you, I have zero experience with RabbitMQ, and this was a quick solution to getting a remote connection to a server brought up from an AWS AMI for experimenting on to see if I should look into it further.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution

Answer (score 41):

> user 'guest' can only connect via localhost

That's true since RabbitMQ 3.3.x. Hence you should upgrade to the same version the client library, or just upgrade Spring AMQP to the latest version (if you use dependency managent system).

Previous version of client used `127.0.0.1` as default value for the `host` option of `ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Hi Artem , 
I have added pom.xml entry for versions of jar.

Ideally I would like to stay away from using guest username & password.

Could you please let me know if you have any pointers usable for a prod ready Use Case/Proof of concept in above senario?

Comment: Sorry, it ins't clear what you mean regarding ` prod ready Use Case/Proof of concept in above senario`, because I don't see any use case questions here. Feel free to creat any user on the RabbitMQ Broker.

Comment: The simple solution is to specify `localhost` like so: `ConnectionFactory("localhost")`

Comment: For azure UbuntuVM, with the azure assigned ip `guest/guest` account works globally! :(

Answer (score 28):

The error

`ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.`

can occur if the credentials that your application is trying to use to connect to RabbitMQ are incorrect or missing.

I had this happen when the RabbitMQ credentials stored in my ASP.NET application's `web.config` file had a value of `""` for the password instead of the actual password string value.

Comment: Yes - Watch out for typos. :-)

Comment: Not only typos but if you are using the URL mode to connect, then only use A-Za-z0-9 set. and do not try to go to more complex URL encoding scheme.

Comment: My lord, my pass was incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

On localhost  , By default  use **'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672'**

So on a remote or hosted RabbitMQ. Let's say you have the following credentials

username: niceboy
password: notnice
host: goxha.com
port : 1597

then the uri you should pass will be

**amqp://niceboy:notnice@goxha.com:1597**

following the template amqp://user:pass@host:10000

if you have a vhost you can do amqp://user:pass@host:10000/vhost where the trailing vhost will be the name of your vhost

Answer (score 8):

To allow guest access remotely, write this

```
[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}].
```

to here

```
c:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.config
```

then restart the rabbitmq windows service (Source https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html)

Answer (score 4):

New solution:

The node module can't handle `:` in a password properly. Even url encoded, like it would work normally, it does not work.

**Don't use typicalspecial characters from an URL in the password!**

Like one of the following: `: . ? + %`

---

Original, wrong answer:

The error message clearly complains about using `PLAIN`, it does not mean the crendentials are wrong, it means you must use encrypted data delivery (TLS) instead of plaintext.

Changing `amqp://` in the connection string to `amqps://` (note the `s`) solves this.

Comment: I was just digging into the code and this was indeed a bug that [has been fixed](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/commit/7acbfd72330b835e1ffdad3daf78c222d1256142) later in 2017 :-)

Comment: You can encode special characters , see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346686/invalid-uri-invalid-port-specified-the-hostname-could-not-be-parsed

Answer (score 4):

just add login password to connect to RabbitMq

```
 CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
         new CachingConnectionFactory("rabbit_host");

 connectionFactory.setUsername("login");
 connectionFactory.setPassword("password");
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was simple: the user name is case sensitive. Failing to use the correct caps will also lead to the error.

Answer (score 2):

if you use the number as your password, maybe you should try to change your password using string.

I can login using deltaqin:000000 on the website, but had this while running the program. then change the password to deltaiqn. and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I made exactly what @grepit made.

But I had to made some changes in my Java code:

In Producer and Receiver project I altered:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("your-host-ip");
factory.setUsername("username-you-created");
factory.setPassword("username-password");
```

Doing that, you are connecting an specific host as the user you have created.
It works for me!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had this error, cuz of wrongly set password (I tried to use 5672, when the actual one in my system was 5676).
Maybe this will help someone to double check ports...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue due to empty space at the end of the password(spring.rabbitmq.password=rabbit ) in spring boot application.properties got resolved on removing the empty space. Hope this checklist helps some one facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For C# coder, I tried below code and It worked, may be this can help someone so posting here.

scenario- RabbitMQ queue is running on another system in local area network but I was having same error.

by default there is a "guest" user exists. but you can not access remote server's queue (rabbitMq) using "guest" user so you need to create new user, Here I created "tester001" user to access data of remote server's queue.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.UserName = "tester001";
factory.Password = "testing";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.HostName = "192.168.1.101";
factory.Port = AmqpTcpEndpoint.UseDefaultPort;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all of these answers for your issue but you still got "ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN", maybe you should remove rabbitmq and install it with a newer version.
Newer version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add one user and pass and connect to them. You can add 1 user via env variables (e.g., useful when Rabbit initializes in a Docker): RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER and RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS. See more details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70676040/1200914

Answer (score 0):

The Solution that worked for me is that in your configuration file like Docker-Compose file or in your Environmental file cheak that you have mention rabbitmq user and password
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user

RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=1234
like this and the error will gone

Answer (score -3):

set ConnectionFactory or Connection hostname to localhost

Comment: This works after change 127.0.0.1 to localhost for docker-hosted local rabbitmq instance.