# Invalid URI: Invalid port specified / The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, ftp, webclient

I'm trying to upload a file to a remote server's FTP.

When I try using:
ftp://user:pass@ftp.host.com/name.txt

I get this error:
***Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.***

When I try using:
ftp://[user:pass@ftp.host.com]/name.txt

as suggested in several posts,

I get this error:
***Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.***

This is my code for upload:

```
using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.UploadFile(new Uri(ftpAddress), @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\name.txt");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the port? `ftp://user:pass@ftp.host.com:21/name.txt`

Comment: Hi @SynderCoder, Yes, I did - same result.

Comment: Hello again, I tried your example with a ftp server I have access to, but I can't reproduce your error. Are you sure you dont have an type error?

Comment: Can you send me the code ?

Comment: var uri = new Uri("ftp://gerard:Passw0rd!@192.168.x.x/123.csv");
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile(uri, "out.csv");
}

Comment: Could it be that your password contains an @ or a : or something so that the uri isn't right anymore?

Comment: The password contains # and a !

Comment: That is indeed the problem. I found the following: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969869 Either the username or the password contains any one of the characters:  : # ? / \ %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your password or username contains a symbol that invalidates the uri. Therefor you should use another way to set the credentials:

```
var uri = new Uri("ftp://ftp.host.com/name.txt"); //no credentails in url
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
    webClient.DownloadFile(uri, @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\name.txt");
}
```

Or you can still use the password in the URL but then you will need to encode the special characters in the following way:

```
# -> %23     
/ -> %2F     
: -> %3A     
? -> %3F     
\ -> %5C     
% -> %25
```