# Add exchanges in rabbitmq with Dockerfile or docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to add three exchanges into rabbitmq before the web service run in docker. My docker-compose.yml is like below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9070
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "9070:8000"

    depends_on:
      -redis
      -rabbitmq

    links:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:latest

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for debugging
      - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin'
```

Any idea to add the exchange into the yml script? The exchange name will be `dataproc`, `dataproc_output` and `mlearning`

Comment: Did you manage to make this work?

Comment: @SkarXa From what I remembered, I just have to access it from localhost:15672 in browser since they are mapped `- "15672:15672" ` and declare exchanges. This is how I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two ways to address this issue:

- [by referencing rabbitmq.config file via **volume**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251266/1155185)
- via temporary configuration [container](https://github.com/mushkevych/scheduler-distro/blob/master/scripts/rabbitmq_config.sh) and [entrypoint script](https://github.com/mushkevych/scheduler-distro/blob/master/scripts/rabbitmq_config.dockerfile#L18)

Option #2 appeals to me more, as the configuration is performed via REST calls.

Comment: second link is dead