# RabbitMQ Admin Can't Log In To Management UI

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running RabbitMQ version 3.7.6 in a Docker container. The management plugin is enabled.

I receive the following error when logging in to the management UI:

[image]

I am using the following `rabbitmq.conf`:

```
default_user                    = admin
default_pass                    = redacted
default_user_tags.administrator = true
default_user_tags.management    = true
```

The confusing part is that it appears user `admin` does indeed have management enabled. The following is shown during boot up:

```
Creating user 'admin'
Setting user tags for user 'admin' to [management,administrator]
Setting permissions for 'admin' in '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'
```

As requested, here is the output of `list_users`:

```
$ rabbitmqctl list_users
Listing users ...
admin   [management, administrator]
```

**Why am I unable to log in to the management console on an account that appears to have the `management` tag enabled?**

Comment: would this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747469/how-to-add-initial-users-when-starting-a-rabbitmq-docker-container

Comment: What is the output of `rabbitmqctl list_users`?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the output of `list_users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my response here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/Gm2L4Yyu8jQ/RRL8QRlGAwAJ

Based on the configuration file you provide in that message thread, you are creating a user named `"admin"` (including the quotes).