# Unable to Access RabbitMQ in the Lan [Windows]

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to access RabbitMQ server in my LAN network, both computers use Windows 7. In my server computer it is running fine, and I can post message in the queue using celery. I verified that the server is running by running

```
rabbitmqctl status
```

Also I have a simple celery code for testing:

```
from celery import Celery
#app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@172.16.17.227//') #this is my lan ip
app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

When I run this command,

```
celery -A celery_test worker --loglevel=info
```

it says

> celery@I-USER ready.

However,

When I try to connect to my server computer from a different machine in the same network with the same celery code except by replacing it with the IP of my computer,

```
app = Celery('hello', broker='amqp://user:user@172.16.17.227//')
```

it says, Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@172.16.17.227//: timed out.

Side Note: I have two users, both of them are administrator. The reason is that [docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) say guest is not allowed to connect without loopback. When I run rabbitmqctl I get :

```
guest [administrator]
user [administrator]
```

My configuration is default (i.e. there is no rabbitmq.config file under %APPDATA%/RabbitMQ folder.

At this point I am running out of ideas. Any Ideas on how to connect to RabbitMQ from a different computer?

Thanks

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I added erlsrv.exe in the allowed programs list in firewall settings. Also tested the port (after turning off rabbitmq) by running a flask server at that port. It runs fine.

Comment: Yes I know the problem:
Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784080/rabbitmq-guest-login-failed

Comment: The guest user is not allowed to connect from remote hosts, whether it is an administrator or not