# Connect to rabbitmq from remote device

Tags: android, windows, rabbitmq

I have rabbitmq in my computer (windows 7 home premium)
i've created a little android app that connects to the rabbit.
In localhost it works fine but when i'm out of my network it doesn't work.
I know it's because i'm using localhost as host, but i don't know how to connect it remotely.

I've  open 15672 in firewall
I try to use the my public ip.
In the config file i've uncomment {tcp_listeners, [5672]} and {loopback_users, []}

and restart the service but it doesn't work

But nothing works

Any help/guidance will be great
Thank you all.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for , i hope , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020908/how-to-access-rabbitmq-publicly

Comment: Thank for the reply, i've already tried those solutions, furthermore, i've created new user with administrator privilages

Comment: What error message is your client getting?